# Auto Populate edit form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

so i made a table that show data from my database and in that table there's an edit button that open a page where you can edit the value of the table and the database, the problem is that i want to know how to auto populate the input form with the value that is selected to be edited

here a snip of the edit form

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="kodeproduksi" class="control-label">Kode Produksi</label>

// form that used dropdown where the option of the dropdown is a data from database
      <select name="kodeproduksi" id="kodeproduksi"  class="form-control">
      <?php foreach($produksi as $prd) : ?>
        <option value ="<?php echo $prd["kodeprod"]; ?>"><?php echo $prd["kodeprod"]; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Item Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    </div>
```

what should i do to auto populate my input box

Comment: i can't understand your question.you have select a value in dropdown box that value should be same in edit page is correct?

Comment: So far i understood that you are having table with multiple rows of data. Each row have an edit button and on clicking that you want to show its data on a new page. Am i right?

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a snippet:

```js
var table = $(".myTable")

// handle click and add class
table.find('tr').on("click", function(){
 alert( $(this).find('input').val() )  
})
```

```css
.myTable td{
  background-color:#eee;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>1
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
  </td>
  <td>other cell
  </td>  
  <td>other cell
  </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2
    <input type="hidden" value="2">
  </td>
  <td>other cell
  </td>  
  <td>other cell
  </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3
    <input type="hidden" value="3">
  </td>
  <td>other cell
  </td>  
  <td>other cell
  </td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see you have:

- a table with an input field inside a cell, one input for row
- a js that attach to every row (tr) the function ad click (if you want you can modify `.find('tr')` with `.find('td')` if you want to attach onclick only to cell)
- inside the function you get the value of input on clicked element `$(this).find('input').val()`

Now you have to change alert with what you want, for example the function that open your form with the prepopulated val

Answer (score 0):

you can set the value inside the single row of the table as:

- an input hidden getting that value on click

`<td>my val<input type="hidden" value="myval"></td>`

- a data-attribute and getting that value on click

`<td data-myval="myval">my val</td>`

- directly inside onClick

`<td onclick="openForm(myval)">my val</td>`

Comment: so i need to add 3 of them in my `<td>`? or i just need one of them?

Comment: Three different solutions, you have to choose the one that better fit your needs!

Comment: so if i had this table `<td><?php echo $dkm["qty"]; ?></td>` i should put it like this `<td><?php echo $dkm["qty"]; ?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dkm["qty"]; ?>"></td>`?

Comment: Yes, and then if you have an onclick function you have to get the value of the input field

Comment: i think im doing it wrong, i do like the one i send it before but the value is blank, i dont have onclick function, same result when i tried the onclick one too tho

Comment: I post you a snippet, in the next answer

Comment: ohh okay that help alot

Comment: You're welcome, if some answer help you don't forget to upvote it